# CsQuery append to

Tags: c#, csquery

I need to append Html element after an existing element in CsQuery, for example:

I've this code

```
        CQ frgt = CQ.CreateFragment("<p>some text</p>");
        CQ html = CQ.CreateFromFile("index.html");

        // I also tried .Append instead of After
        string x = html.Select("#test").After(frgt).Render();
```

index.html content:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <title></title>
     </head>
     <body>
         <div id="page">
             <div class="test">
                    <p>test</p>
                 </div>
         </div>
     </body>
 </html>
```

The rendered string doesn't contain the 'frgt' content!
What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: What the rendered string show up?

Comment: same index.html, without the node i appended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector `#test` in this line:

```
string x = html.Select("#test").After(frgt).Render();
```

is looking for an element with `id="test"`. Your HTML only has an element with *class* test. Probably you want:

```
string x = html.Select(".test").After(frgt).Render();
```

.. to select the node with class `test`.